# С# проблема с отрисовкой на форме после её увеличения

Tags: c#

У меня программа Windows Forms с двумя кнопками (button1 и button2). При нажатии кнопки button1: на форме отрисовывается сетка (вроде ячеек для сапера 10x10 ячеек), а затем размер формы уменьшается до размеров поля. Здесь все работает замечательно.

Но когда я нажимаю кнопку button2 (проблема возникает даже если не нажимать на button1) у меня форма увеличивается, (задаётся 15x15 ячеек), но на форме отрисовывается не полностью.

Вот как получается если нажать на вторую кнопку.
[image: Вот как получается, если нажать на вторую кнопку]

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddPanelTest
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics g;
        int rows = 10;
        int cols = 10;
        int cellsize = 25;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button srcButton = (Button) sender;
            if (srcButton == button1)
            {
                rows = 10; cols = 10;
                draw();
                resizeForm();
            }
            else
            {
                rows = 15; cols = 15;
                resizeForm(); 
                draw();                
            }
        }

        private void myPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            draw();           
        }

        private void draw()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) 
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
                {
                    int xCoord = x * cellsize;
                    int yCoord = y * cellsize;
                    Rectangle cell = new Rectangle(xCoord, yCoord, cellsize, cellsize);
                    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, cell);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell);
                }
            }
        }

        public void resizeForm()
        {
            //this.Width = cols* cellsize;
            //this.Height = rows * cellsize;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(cols * cellsize+1, rows * cellsize+1);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас `myPanel_Paint` - это обработчик события `Paint` формы, то его код нужно переписать так:

```
g = CreateGraphics();
draw();
```

а из конструктора `g = CreateGraphics();` можно убрать

---

Если почитать документацию по методу [`CreateGraphics()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics(v=vs.110).aspx) можно реализовать более правильное использование получаемого объекта `Graphics`, перепишите метод `draw()`:

```
private void draw()
{
    using (var g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
            {
                int xCoord = x * cellsize;
                int yCoord = y * cellsize;
                Rectangle cell = new Rectangle(xCoord, yCoord, cellsize, cellsize);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.GreenYellow, cell);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А из остальных мест `g` удалите.

Дело в том, что объект `Graphics` представляет собой область рисования, а она меняется при любом изменении размеров или видимости формы.

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь получилось!

Comment: @tonique, дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое за ваш ответ! мне это очень помогло!